# repl.bat extrace text between space and numbers

Tags: batch-file

Trying to extract the text between a space and some numbers to a new output 
This is the input line for job notes
Job Notes=John Smith 123456 11/22/3333 1:22:33 PM 654321

```
@echo off
set "input=before.txt"
set "output=after.txt"
findstr /r /i /c:"^Job Notes=" "%input%" |repl ".*=(.*) (\d+) (\d+\/\d+\/\d+) \d+:\d+:\d+ .*" "Name=$1\r\nFile Number=$2\r\nDate=$3" x >"%output%"
findstr /r /i /c:"^File Type=" "%input%" >>"%output%"
findstr /r /i /c:"^Location="  "%input%" >>"%output%"
```

Currently get this output.

```
Name=John Smith
File Number=123456
Date=dd/MM/yyyy
File Type=4
Location=3
```

Would like this output

```
Name=John Smith
Lastname=Smith
File Number=123456
Date=dd/MM/yyyy
File Type=4
Location=3
```

I need to extract all text from the space to the numbers to account for last names with spaces in them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the right regular expression to do that:

```
repl ".*=(\w* (\w*)) (\d+) (\d+\/\d+\/\d+) \d+:\d+:\d+ .*" "Name=$1\r\nLastname=$2\r\nFile Number=$3\r\nDate=$4" x >"%output%"
```